# Using Arduino Flora as a general purpose ID badge

Tags: arduino, wifi, rfid

I am a s/w guy, only just getting into embedded programming, with little or no knowledge of hardware .

I love the look of the new Flora wearable [Arduino](https://www.adafruit.com/products/659) and would like to try a few simple projects to teach myself some new skills, maybe a new hobby.

With BlueTooth and GPS, I can see some possibilities as an intelligent Id badge. And here come my dumb h/w questions ...

1) could I add Wifi to this? Is it cheap and easy to do, both in terms of hardware and software?

2) what about RFID? I suppose I could just stick a passive Id tag on to it an leave it at that. But, can I attach an active RFID tag and have the MCU be aware that the RFID tag has been scanned by a read?

I hope that doesn't sound too dumb and thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Some wacky and crazy wearable badges are shown at [hackaday:badge](http://hackaday.com/tag/badge/) and elsewhere [a](http://unstdio.org/category/badge/) [b](http://greatscottgadgets.com/tc13badge/), a few of them Arduino-compatible.

Comment: Some great info there. You ought to have posted an answer. Thanks :-)

Comment: Seven years later and this long forgotten question gets a drive-by downvote - welcome to Stack Exchange :-/ NVM, it gives Me the opportunity to say that Blue Tooth Low Energy ids the way to go. The BT 5 standard adds proximity features which ought to take some of the sting out of triangulation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can find wifi modules with a serial interface that would work.

However, by the time you add the wifi module, you've increased the size to the point where you might as well use a regular arduino.

With a regular arduino you can add a wifi shield pretty easily.

As for your RFID idea, the easiest way would be to find an active tag that has an LED on it that blinks when it's transmitting, and then run a connection from that output to the microcontroller (would require some soldering).